# How to enable or disable other services when booting linux

Tags: linux, boot, init

Assume i have 3 services, A, B and C, the booting priority is A>B>C which means A is the first  service to run while C is the last, in /etc/rc.d/rc3.d directory, it may looks like:

```
# ll /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Mar  5  2013 S00service_A -> ../init.d/A
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 19 Feb 26  2013 S05service_B -> ../init.d/B
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 Feb 26  2013 S10service_C -> ../init.d/C
```

In service A, it will grep /proc/cmdline to find some special boot flag, if the flag is on A should disable service B and enable service C, if this flag is off then A should disable service C and enable service B.
I tried call chkconfig B/C on/off in service A, but it doesn't work, anyone know the best way to do this job?

Comment: This is probably better asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to create a small script, e.g. `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/0initservice` which will act as a service and that will check your boot flag and start the appropriate services from the script.